# Qt: I would to know how can i display my result to the table in main window

Tags: qt, tableview

I want to know how I can display my result to the table in the main window.

My program is simple; the user enters two numbers in two line edits and once the user clicks the *Run* button it will display all odd numbers between the numbers that the user has entered. I can  show the result but in a text browser.

I add that line in my slot function and i get the result in the text browser:

```
ui->textbrowser->setText(QString(%1).arg(result));
```

How can I show result in the table view? I can create the table but I don't know what I should use to show the result in my window.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Qt's Model/View tutorial

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html

From there, an example (although it uses a TreeView):

```
 // modelview.cpp
 #include <QTreeView>
 #include <QStandardItemModel>
 #include <QStandardItem>
 #include "mainwindow.h"

 const int ROWS = 2;
 const int COLUMNS = 3;

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
     : QMainWindow(parent)
 {
     treeView = new QTreeView(this);
     setCentralWidget(treeView);
     standardModel = new QStandardItemModel ;

     QList<QStandardItem *> preparedRow =prepareRow("first", "second", "third");
     QStandardItem *item = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();
     // adding a row to the invisible root item produces a root element
     item->appendRow(preparedRow);

     QList<QStandardItem *> secondRow =prepareRow("111", "222", "333");
     // adding a row to an item starts a subtree
     preparedRow.first()->appendRow(secondRow);

     treeView->setModel(standardModel);
     treeView->expandAll();
 }

 QList<QStandardItem *> MainWindow::prepareRow(const QString &first,
                                                 const QString &second,
                                                 const QString &third)
 {
     QList<QStandardItem *> rowItems;
     rowItems << new QStandardItem(first);
     rowItems << new QStandardItem(second);
     rowItems << new QStandardItem(third);
     return rowItems;
 }
```